# How many times x is divisible by y using function

Tags: python, function, integer

So, basically I have to built an algorithm that tells me how many times X is divisible by Y. If its not divisible, it should return print -1.

Here's what i've got so far:

```
def divisible(x, y):
 n = int(x/y)
 if (n != 0 and x%y == 0):
   print(x, "its divisible by",y,n,"times")
 else:
    print(-1)

divisible(5, 2)
```

The exercise its asking to use a counter to do this. How can I make It?

Thanks

Comment: for loop and subtraction?

Comment: Can you clarify what you would like it to do and what it is doing wrong now?

Comment: In your research before posting this question, what do you understand a counter to be? How can its conceptual use be incorporated into this function?

Comment: Do you need to consider x<0 and/or y<0?

Comment: counter, something like:
``` 
cont=0
 for i in range(2,n-1):
  if (n % i == 0):
     cont += 1
```

Comment: both x and y can be > 0 or <0. The question says nothing about that.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input/output?

Answer (score -2):

Integer division and the modulo function should get you there -

```py
divisible = lambda x, y: x // y if x % y == 0 else -1
divisible(13, 3)
# -1
divisible(12, 3)
# 4
```

Comment: Not if the requirement is to use a "counter", it won't.

Comment: Additionally, if assigning a name to a `lambda` function, create a proper `def`.

Comment: @ScottHunter - Yes, totally missed the "counter" part

Answer (score -2):

```
def divisible (x, y):
    # Initialize times to keep track of how many times x is
    # divisible by y:
    times = 0
    # Enter an infinite loop:
    while True:
        # If the remainder of x divided by y is 0
        # (= if x is divisible by y):
        if ( x % y == 0 ):
            # Increment times by 1 and actually divide x by y:
            times += 1
            x = x / y
        # If x is *not* divisible by y, break out of the infinite loop:
        else:
            break
    # If the original x was not divisible by y at all, return -1
    # (otherwise, keep times unchanged):
    if times == 0:
        times = -1
    return times
    
print(divisible(2, 2))
# 1

print(divisible(3, 2))
# -1

print(divisible(8, 2))
# 3

print(divisible(10000, 2))
# 4
```

Comment: Care to explain how this code works, step by step? Sorry, im new. Thank you.

Comment: also, with larger numbers it doesnt work... try print(divisible(10000, 5))

Comment: @alberto: Added explanations, fixed bug.

Comment: @alberto: Note that `times` is the counter.

Comment: And what should I modify in order to show not only the integer divisible times, but the remain also? like (6,2) is one, but theres 3 that is left. and then print something like ("It is divisible x times, and left over y)?